# Rails 3 automatic asset deployment to Amazon CloudFront?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, amazon-cloudfront

**Is there a gem or method available in Rails 3.1 that can upload assets to amazon cloud front automatically and use those instead of serving locally hosted ones?** I guess it's easy to upload compiled assets manually and then change the rails app config to use that asset host, but when an asset is modified, the uploads to cloud front would need to be done manually again. Any good ways out there for this?

Answer (score 14):

Definitely check out **asset_sync** on github. Or our Heroku dev centre article on [Using a CDN asset Host with Rails 3.1 on Heroku](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cdn-asset-host-rails31).

There is quite a big performance improvement in using **asset_sync** vs a CDN custom origin, letting your application lazily compile assets in production or serving them precompiled directly off your app servers. However I would say that. I wrote it.

- With asset_sync and S3 you can precompile assets meaning all the assets are there ready to be served on the asset host / CDN immediately
- You can only require the **:assets** bundle in application.rb on precompile, saving memory in production
- Your app servers are NEVER hit for asset requests. You can spend expensive compute time on, you know. Computing.
- Best practice HTTP cache headers are all set by default
- You can enable automatic gzip compression with one extra config

Comment: do you know of a reason for why the HTTP cache headers would not be set by default? Do they now have to be set manually in the asset_sync config file? something like config.custom_headers = { 'Cache-Control' => 'max-age=315576000', 'Expires' => 1.year.from_now.httpdate }  i cant seem to get mine to set anything...any help appreciated

Answer (score 11):

If you use Cloudfronts “Custom origin” option you do not need to upload anything, Cloudfront will fetch the assets from your server when needed. For details of setting this up see:

http://blog.ertesvag.no/post/10720082458

Comment: ...and for those using elastic beanstalk, given your assets are likely precompiled by default, the nginx server is going to serve them up to cloudfront so there should be very little consequence to this approach (the request never hits the rails app).

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync - we're using it just to S3 but I guess the CloudFront part is pretty easy once the assets are on S3.

It's ends up being a rake task that you just add to execute in your deployment process.

Answer (score 1):

another option would be https://github.com/moocode/asset_id, the readme has an example to use it with cloudfront. 
It should work with rails 3.1 but I have only used it on 3.0.x.

Ss John said all solutions would end up being a rake task + a bit of logic to change the asset path in rails.