# Background image issue in Rails 3.1 asset pipe line with cloudfront CDN

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, amazon-s3, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I have a rails 3.1.0  heroku app  that uses Amazon cloudfront cdn to deliver assets.Everything works fine except for the background image, its not rendered.Inspecting the request in firebug/Yslow  shows 
`GET box.png 403 Forbidden d2g4atxxxxxx.cloudfront.net  231 B 54.240.xxx.xxx:xx` 
and the url to the image is `http://d2g4xxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/assets/box.png`.As you can see it is not the image is not fingerprinted.In application.css i have this `background-image:url('box.png');` 
**Things that i tried**

**1st try**

I appended .erb to  application.css and added `background-image:url(<%=asset_path 'box.png'%>);`
Then i added   `config.action_controller.asset_host="http://mybucket_name.com.s3.amazonaws.com"`
 Then i did

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Then i switched back to

```
config.action_controller.asset_host ="http://d2gxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net"
```

Then i did

```
 git add application.css.erb
 git commit -a
 git push origin master
```

But it didn't work

**2nd try**

I appended .scss to  application.css and added `background-image:image-url('box.png');`
Then i added   `config.action_controller.asset_host="http://mybucket_name.com.s3.amazonaws.com"`
 Then i did

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Then i switched back to

```
config.action_controller.asset_host ="http://d2gxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net"
```

Then i did

Then i added   `gem 'compass-rails'` to a gemfile   and created compass.rb and added this

```
   #In compass.rb
  project_type = :rails
  line_comments = false
  generated_images_dir = "public/assets"


 bundle install
 git add application.css.scss  compass.rb
 git commit -a
 git push origin master
```

But also it didn't work

**What I have**

gemfile

```
  source 'http://rubygems.org'

  gem 'rails', '3.1.0.rc8'


  group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  end
  gem 'geocoder'
  gem "dynamic_form"
  gem 'devise'
  gem 'rack', '1.3.3'
  gem 'execjs'
  gem 'carrierwave'
  gem "meta_search",'>= 1.1.0.pre'
  gem "thumbs_up"
  gem 'geocoder'
  gem 'fog'
  gem 'koala'



   group :production do
   gem 'pg'
   gem 'therubyracer'
   gem 'unicorn'

   end
   gem 'jquery-rails'
   gem 'thin'

   gem 'mongrel', '1.2.0.pre2', :group => :development

   gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.1.0.rc"
   gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0.rc"
   gem 'uglifier'
   gem 'yui-compressor'
   gem "asset_sync"
  # gem 'compass-rails'


   group :test do
   # Pretty printed test output
   gem 'turn', :require => false
   gem 'rspec-rails'
   gem "factory_girl_rails"
   gem 'capybara'
   gem "guard-rspec"
   end
```

app/config/enviroenments/production.rb

```
    Deals::Application.configure do

    config.cache_classes = true

   # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.action_controller.asset_host ="http://d2g4xxxxxx.cloudfront.net"

  config.serve_static_assets = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true
   config.assets.compile = true
    config.assets.digest = true
   config.assets.css_compressor = :yui
    config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
      config.i18n.fallbacks = true
    config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
    end
```

**Question**

What am i doing wrong?or what step am i missing, can somebody walk me through the steps please?I have spend the whole week reading different blogs and different  questions about this with no luck.Thanks in advance

Comment: when you tried accessing the background image with your browser,is it working properly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use custom origins with CloudFront instead of S3. That means that CloudFront points to your Rails app instead of S3. This will cause all your assets to be versioned for you and may fix your problem.

Here's an article about CloudFront with custom origins when using the Rails Asset Pipeline. You can google more on the topic:

http://blog.ertesvag.no/post/10720082458

Here's another SO question with more info:

[Rails 3 automatic asset deployment to Amazon CloudFront?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354514/rails-3-automatic-asset-deployment-to-amazon-cloudfront)

Comment: That is a good option but i have alot of images though, so i wanted them in s3 bucket.

Comment: Before you spend too much time with CSS, make sure the images are accessible via direct link to S3. 403 Forbidden means your permissions are not setup correctly on the S3 bucket. Make sure you've allowed everyone to access files in your bucket. Is that what "doesn't work" with each try?

Comment: The rest of images are loaded correctly from s3, just the background-image only has issues.

Comment: Last option - copy the non-fingerprinted version of the image into the bucket manually, then hard-code the full URL in your css.  Test the url first and make sure you have it right.